# host_permissions vs activeTab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

What are the main differences between host_permissions and activeTab, they seem to be similar

for exmaple this privilege

- List item the ability to read tab-specific metadata without the "tabs" permission, such as the url, title, and favIconUrl properties of tabs.Tab objects

For activeTab I'll be able to do this only once the user interacts with the extension and with host_permissions I'll be able to do this regardless?

I need to read the url of every linkedin page the user visits without the user interacting with the extension but I'm concerned about host_permissions justification for https://www.linkedin.com/* in the review

Answer (score 0):

It's looks the same, but the serve different purposes.
If you don't using host_permissions your extenshion will work on any tabs and loads on any website.
Without activeTab or tabs permission you can't get access from tab object.

It looks good I think.

```
"host_permissions": ["https://www.linkedin.com/*"],
```

Comment: Take it slow and make sure your spelling and grammar are on point, or people won't take you as seriously. No offense, and welcome!